# Why it is better approach to create Exception Hierarchy, rather than simply create all exceptions at same level

Tags: exception

I am learning about the exceptions and I read somewhere that we have to always create exception hierarchy, rather than simply creating all exception at same level. I am not able to understand why it is so.

Example:

```
Why This
Exception --> ATMException --> 1. ATMAuthException -->  1.1 WrongATMCardException
                                                        1.2 WrongATMPinException 
                               2. WithdrawException --> 2.1 InsufficientBalanceException

Not This
Exception --> ATMException --> 1. WrongATMCardException
                               2. WrongATMPinException
                               3. InsufficientBalanceException
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you create an exception below. What if you want to catch both exceptions and handles them.

```
public void foo1() throws WrongATMCardException, WrongATMPinException {}

public void foo2(){
   try{
      // do stuff..
   }catch(WrongATMCardException ex){
       foo3();
   }catch(WrongATMPinException ex){
       foo3();
   }
}
public void foo3(){
   System.out.println("ATM login failed. Throwing authentication failed exception");
   // throw NO exception handles both. ???  
}
```

But if you declare exceptions like above, you can handle both exception by `throwing ATMAuthException` and handle, throws exceptions easily.

```
public void foo1() throws WrongATMCardException, WrongATMPinException {}

public void foo2(){
   try{
      // do stuff..
   }catch(ATMException ex){
       foo3();
   }
}
public void foo3(){
   System.out.println("ATM login failed. Throwing authentication failed exception");
   throw new ATMException(); //single exception that handles all children.
}
```

In other case, you can throws all exceptions one by one. But what if you have 10, 20 exceptions that is all about basically ATM exception. You have to throw and catch these exceptions everywhere, which occurs later to complexity level of your code.

Comment: Yes, it's one use case for creating clean-code. It will be better if you can suggest some other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you create hierarchical exceptions, you can then catch them at once in the `try {} catch ()` statement, and you don't have to do this for each one separately.

Example:

```
try {
...
} catch (ATMAuthException e) {
...
}
```

is better than

```
try {
...
} catch (WrongATMCardException | WrongATMPinException e) {
...
}
```